rational map by F. Mangolte
I'm reading Real Algebraic Varieties by F. Mangolte.
Definition 1.3.22 (in the book)
If $X$ and $Y$ are algebraic varieties over a base field $K$ a rational
map $\phi:X\dashrightarrow Y$ is an equivalence class of pairs $(U,\phi_{U})$ where $U$ is a dense open subset of $X$, $\phi_{U}$ is a map from $U$ to $Y$ and two pairs $(U,\phi_{U})$ and $(V,\phi_{V})$ are equivalent if and only if $\phi_{U}$ and $\phi_{V}$ are identical on the intersection $U\cap V$.
I think in the definition, $\phi_{U}$ should be a morphism or something, not just a map. Since I'm a beginner at algebraic geometry, I can't be confident.

Yes, sure, he means "a morphism".
